# Cufon Wont Load in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-11, cufon

I can't seem to figure out the reason that Cufon won't load on IE11 using Edge mode (Developer Tools). If I switch over to IE10 mode the site loads perfectly fine - however with Edge mode on IE11 Cufon refuses to load up.

Any ideas with this?

http://rapidpurple.com

Comment: Why not use [@font-face](http://www.font-face.com/)?

Comment: Trying to implement that now HOWEVER I constantly get the following:

@font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.

Even though I am calling locally referenced files.

Comment: Disregard. Sorted that.

Comment: Got it sorted with the use of @font-face however I am still curious what broke Cufon in IE11.

Comment: Not sure, but apparently [you are not the only one](http://shotgunflat.com/journal/cufon-doesnt-work-in-ie11) experiencing that issue. Glad you got it sorted out with @font-face.

Comment: @APAD1 nice to know it's not just me. I looked around for a while for a similar issue and it seems everyone has Cufon issues with IE8/9/10 and no mention of IE11 issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue myself, and also had trouble finding an answer online, so I thought this must be a really specific issue. I've opened the IE dev tools, checked the console, and there was this curious error:

SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

File: ligthbox.css

The error is not correctly reported, as the css file is served with correct mime type, but the thing was actually that it failed to get the file due to the page being rewritten with htaccess into /some-directory/ and the lightbox.css file was included without the leading slash, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

After I added the leading slash, the error was gone from the console, and the Cufon loaded correctly.